How does the fight ability work when the creature instigating the fight is recast?
Suppose Brash Taunter's fight ability is activated targeting some other creature to fight with Brash Taunter. A stack is started with that ability on the bottom. Next Unsummon is cast targeting Brash Taunter and it goes to the top of the stack. Unsummon is allowed to resolve and Brash Taunter is returned to its owners hand, leaving only the fight ability left on the stack. Now suppose the owner of Brash Taunter has some way to cast Brash Taunter as an instant. They do so, so that the spell casting Brash Taunter goes to the top of the stack, just above Brash Taunter's activated ability, which has been there from the start. Brash Taunter is allowed to resolve.
Now what happens to Brash Taunter's original activated ability? Does it resolve as originally intended since Brash Taunter is back on the battlefield?

No, this does not work. When Brash Traunter re-enters the battlefield, it is a new object. See rule 400.7 in the comprehensive rules:

400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. This rule has the following exceptions. [The exceptions don't apply]

But, you may ask: why does that matter? Brash Taunter's ability doesn't say anything about which object does the fighting. Unfortunately, the fine print is specific that the ability only refers to the exact same Brash Taunter.

201.5. Text that refers to the object it’s on by name means just that particular object and not any other objects with that name, regardless of any name changes caused by game effects.

So when the card says "Brash Taunter fights target creature." That can be translated as "this object fights target creature." And any change in zones makes a new object.
Finally, we can address what happens when a creature that has left the battlefield tries to fight:

701.12b If one or both creatures instructed to fight are no longer on the battlefield or are no longer creatures, neither of them fights or deals damage. If one or both creatures are illegal targets for a resolving spell or ability that instructs them to fight, neither of them fights or deals damage.

They don't fight and nothing happens.

Great answer. Thank you.

Hasn't this material been covered many times before here?
